# Music-play shortcut for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, music

I want to continue the music in any player (or most of them [windows media player, spotify...]) with a windows (7) shortcut, like some buttons on some keyboards do. Is this even possible, i just found media player intern shortcuts like the CTRL-P for playing and CTRL-S for stopping.

Comment: There is no hotkey working in every player.

Answer (score 0):

Some keyboards have media buttons including a play button. Many media programs will respond to these buttons, and when a program allows custom keyboard shortcuts, they can often be programmed to follow these. Other than that, there's no way to force programs to respond to this code, because you can't bind a key to this virtual key. (at least not that I'm aware of)

So it is dependend on the program to accept these multi-media keys, and you need a keyboard that has these.